# Confusion on the definition of Inverse relations

Tags: real-analysis, functions, definition

Can you shed some light on this statement?

> Let $:  → $ be a function. Define a new relation $^{−1}$ :
> $() \to $ in the  following manner. $$^{−1} () = ;\space\space where\space () = .$$ This $^{−1}$ is called the
> inverse relation of $$. It is not always a function.

The problem I have is with $^{−1} : \color{red}{()} \to $.
In every book on Functions that I've read and in Wikipedia, I've seen that it is
$^{−1} : \color{blue}{B} \to $.

Comment: As stated, the definition is not very clear, as it does not says (1) what a relation is, and (2) what $R(f)$ is.

Comment: @ElchananSolomon Here the term "relation" has its usual definition and $R(f)$ is the range of $f$.

Comment: @PavanPitiwaduge My usual definition of a relation between sets $X$ and $Y$ is a subset of the product $X \times Y$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @ElchananSolomon Yes, that's right.

Comment: @PavanPitiwaduge The above definition does not define a subset of $A \times B$ so I cannot say it is consistent with such a definition of a relation.

Comment: I would rephrase the question as something along the lines of, "Can you shed some light on this statement?" I'm not sure what you mean when you ask if that definition is "correct" because a definition is an exact, unambiguous explanation of what a mathematical word/phrase means. We don't try to show whether a definition is correct or incorrect. Or you can ask, "Does this definition make sense?"

Comment: @ElchananSolomon The statement says that $f$ is a function and that $f:A \to B$. Hence $f$ is a relation and $f \subseteq A \times B$

Comment: @PavanPitiwaduge A function from $A$ to $B$ is not the same thing as a subset of $A \times B$, the latter is more general, and allows for an element in $A$ to correspond to multiple elements in $B$, which is what is needed for $f^{-1}$. I'm still not convinced the definition is given clearly and consistently.

Comment: This doesn't look like a good definition to me. The inverse relation should have domain $B$ as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $R(f)$ is the range of $f$, yes, it makes sense. When yu talk about Wikipedia, I suppose that you have in mind the concept of inverse function, which usually is defined only for bijections. And, if $f$ is a bijection, its range is $B$. But the definition that you mentioned makes sense for every function $f$. And the relation $f^{-1}$ is a function (with domain $R(f)$) if and only if $f$ is injective.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the part about bijections. I think I get what you're trying to say; But if you could elaborate more on this statement you said "But the definition that you mentioned makes sense for every function $f$", that would be great.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see *how* I could elaborate more on that. Don't you agree that the definition that you have provided makes sense for every function?

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thank you. This helped me to realize what I need all along

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.